# HAML markdown rendering and showing ERB within

Tags: haml, markdown, erb

I have this in one of my HAML templates:

```
:markdown
  #{render 'home.md'}
```

and in `home.md` I have:

```
There are **#{@photo_count}** photos.
```

When viewing the site, it literally outputs that. How can I get the @photo_count variable to be interpolated?

Answer (score 1):

For a pure Markdown file, I don't think you'll be able to do what you want as the format itself won't support your Ruby variable.

If you don't mind changing your markdown file to a HAML partial file (no need to change its content), you could do something like this (I've used something similar to the code below using the [RDiscount](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount) gem; your mileage may vary with other Markdown gems...):

**app/controllers/pages_controller.rb**

```
def home
  @photo_count = 10
end
```

**app/views/pages/home.html.haml**

```
:markdown
  #{render 'home_page'}
```

**app/views/pages/_home_page.html.haml**

```
There are **#{@photo_count}** photos.
```

See also this StackOverflow Q&A for other ideas:

- [How can I automatically render partials using markdown in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4163560/567863)