# Ruby Regex : Replace tag type

Tags: ruby, regex

So from this string :

```
str = 'Hello #{name}, you are now #{age}.'
```

I'd like to get

```
"Hello <%= name %>, you are now <%= age =>"
```

I tried this :

```
str.gsub(/\#{*}/, "<%= \1 %>")
```

but I it won't work.

Comment: Seems like you are using Ruby to modify Ruby source code. Isn't this something your text editor can do?

Comment: Well it's more complicated that that. I have .html.md views and partials using this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10131299/1620081 but I need a simpler way than `<%= %>` to access variables, since non-technical people will be editing the .md views. I also thought of mustache syntax like `str = 'Hello {{name}}, you are now {{age}}.'` I'll have to figure out both solutions ... Anyway, it was simply a regex question!

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use a template language like Mustache, Handlebars or Liquid. User supplied content should not be passed to ERB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To capture group you have to surround that part with parentheses.

```
str = 'Hello #{name}, you are now #{age}.'
str.gsub(/#\{(.*?)\}/, '<%= \1 %>')
# => "Hello <%= name %>, you are now <%= age %>."
```

And, you have to escape `{`, `}`, not `#`. (`{`, `}` have special meaning in regular expression, while `#` does not).

Comment: why not this `str.gsub('#{','<%= ').gsub('}',' >')` ? :)

Comment: @Babai because you can have strings which contains `#{` but not `}` and vice versa.