# How to replace all html tags of one kind with another

Tags: html, ruby, string

I need to replace all HTML tags of one kind in a string with another, e.g., replace all `<i>` tags with `<em>` tag.

What's the best way to effectively change:

```
"<p><i>Random stuff here...</i></p>"
```

to the following?

```
"<p><em>Random stuff here...</em></p>"
```

There are millions of such strings, so a solution taking complexity into account would be nice.

Comment: If your html tags are into files, you can posibly use your code editor, Visual Code have a find and replace tool, but if your html tags are saved into a database you will probably need to replace the tags from a script, Gsub is your frind. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587022/ruby-regex-replace-tag-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use [**`gsub`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) with block

```
string = "<p><i>Random stuff here...</i></p>"

string.gsub(/(<\/?)i(>)/) { "#{$1}em#{$2}" }
#=> "<p><em>Random stuff here...</em></p>"
```

Explanation:

Match an `i` html opening or closing tag and replace it with `em`