# Get rmarkdown to completely ignore inline and/or block?

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

**What I'd like to do:**

I'd like to use rmarkdown to ***create*** rails `*.html.erb` files.

If you're unfamiliar with `*.html.erb` files, they're basically html files with ruby enclosed between `<%` and `%>` or between `<%=` and `%>` (latter if result should be included in final html rendering).

**Problem:**

I can not find a way to get rmarkdown to ignore `<%`, `%>`, `<%=` and everything between them.

**Q:** Any ideas how this might be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you could write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) to convert code blocks with your special stuff to raw HTML. alternatively: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163560/how-can-i-automatically-render-partials-using-markdown-in-rails-3/10131299#10131299

Comment: Perfect. Best solution for me is indeed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163560/how-can-i-automatically-render-partials-using-markdown-in-rails-3/10131299#10131299 Thanks @mb21