# Using ERB in Markdown with Redcarpet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, redcarpet, ruby-on-rails-6, high-voltage

I'm trying to get Markdown to play nicely with .erb. I'd like to use high_voltage to render markdown pages (or normal .html.erb files with markdown partials) that are parsed with Redcarpet and am struggling to get it to all work together.

At the moment I have an initializer called `markdown_template_handler.rb` that contains the following code:

```rb
class MarkdownTemplateHandler
  def erb
    @erb ||= ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)
  end

  def call(template)
    compiled_source = erb.call(template)
    markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)

    "#{markdown.render(compiled_source.source).inspect}.html_safe;"
  end
end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(:md, MarkdownTemplateHandler.new)
```

However it is failing at line 7, `compiled_source = erb.call(template)` with the error code saying "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)"

I looked at the [ERB Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new) but from what I understood, the call method is a derivative of the new method, which only requires 1 argument, the text. However, when I tried to use it just in a quick rails console session, it also required two arguments.

When I remove the requirement to parse erb from the above code, everything works as expected, so I don't think it has anything to do with Redcarpet not working.

I am using Rails v6.0.0.rc1 & Ruby v2.5.3p105

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

Further research has led me to finding the [Rails 6.0 ERB ActionView template handler.](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template/Handlers/ERB.html#method-i-call) The call method of this handler does indeed require two arguments, the template and the source. That said, in [Rails 5.2.3, the ERB Action View template handler call method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template/Handlers/ERB.html#method-i-call) only requires one argument, the template.

Could someone please point me in the direction of figuring out what *source* is in this context? There is no documentation for it that I can find.

---

Answer (score 7):

In this case, source would be passed to the `call` by ActionView when the handler is called.

You would rewrite your `call` function like that:

```
def call(template, source)
  compiled_source = erb.call(template, source)
  markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)

  "#{markdown.render(compiled_source).inspect}.html_safe;"
end
```

Before Rails 6, the `source` value was extracted from  `template.source`, but it is now passed as a separate parameter.

Answer (score 6):

This approach for rendering markdown with ERB in Rails 6 worked well for me.  Thanks to Louis-Michel for pointing me in the right direction, including both parameters in the call.

```
require 'redcarpet'

class MarkdownTemplateHandler

  def erb
    @erb ||= ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)
  end

  def call(template, source)
    compiled_source = erb.call(template, source)
    "Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new).render(begin;#{compiled_source};end).html_safe"
  end

end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(:md, MarkdownTemplateHandler.new)
```

Comment: This works great for me with Rails 7

Comment: I get the error, `wrong argument type ActionView::OutputBuffer (expected String)`. It looks like it's from a render call. Digging into it.

Comment: Maybe the Redcarpet#render API changed. This works in Rails 7.1 (adding .to_s): `"Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new).render(begin;#{compiled_source};end.to_s).html_safe"`

Comment: @Dogweather It's not because of Redcarpet#render API change. It's because of change in Rails 7.1 ActionView. I wrote down details here, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77549305/9185715