# Using ERB in Markdown with Redcarpet in Rails 7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, ruby-on-rails-7, redcarpet

I am trying to add Markdown support in Rails 7.1.1 app.
Redcarpet gem version is 3.6.0.

I follow advice from this question:
[Using ERB in Markdown with Redcarpet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715152/using-erb-in-markdown-with-redcarpet)

My current code (in `/config/initializers/markdown_handler.rb`) is:

```
module MarkdownHandler
  def self.erb
    @erb ||= ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)
  end

  def self.call(template, source)
    compiled_source = erb.call(template, source)
    "Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new).render(begin;#{compiled_source};end).html_safe"
  end
end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :md, MarkdownHandler
```

And I get an error:
`ActionView::Template::Error: wrong argument type ActionView::OutputBuffer (expected String)`

Could someone kindly explain why is it happening and how to fix it, please?

Answer (score 2):

The custom template handler uses compiled output from `ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB`.
The output was String but since Rails 7.1 it's `ActionView::OutputBuffer` (https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ee68644c284aa7512d06b4b5514b1236c1b63f55).
Commit message describes why this change was made:

> With the recent changes to OutputBuffer, calling `to_s` is extremely expensive if the buffer later is concatenated to (if the buffer never changes it should be relatively inexpensive, as Ruby will share memory).

So we see an error:
`ActionView::Template::Error: wrong argument type ActionView::OutputBuffer (expected String)`

To fix it we can simply convert to String:

```
module MarkdownHandler
  def self.erb
    @erb ||= ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)
  end

  def self.call(template, source)
    compiled_source = erb.call(template, source)
    "Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new).render(begin;#{compiled_source};end.to_s).html_safe"
  end
end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :md, MarkdownHandler
```